# Connecting circuit with raspberry pi

Tags: pi-3b+

I have a dedicated circuit that has a proximity sensor and every time it detects an object the motor is rotated.

I want to connect my Raspberry Pi to it and control the motor as well as the proximity sensor.

Comment: And what is it you'd like to know?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103741/discussion-on-question-by-vicky-connecting-circuit-with-raspberry-pi).